# How do I see which thread was executed before from a breakpoint?

Tags: windows, kernel, windbg

As in the subject, how do I see which thread was executed before from a breakpoint in kernel mode?

Scenario: Have a function that calls multiple functions serially. Suddenly the system thread that is executing the function is pre-empted in the middle. How do I find out which thread pre-empted it?

```
void funcbig()
{

funca();
funcb();
<another thread pre-empts>
funcc(); // this function executes few hundread milliseconds later

}
```

Comment: Please describe some steps to reproduce your problem.

Comment: try .lastevent if that is what you mean

Comment: context switch is likely not an event. I will however give it a try